# Uppercase the author names shown in citation call-outs generated by \citep

Tags: natbib

I need a help, please.

I'm using \citep command to cite a reference, and the result is "(Zhang e Zu, 1999; Zhang et al., 2001)".

But my I need the result as "(ZHANG e ZU, 1999; ZHANG et al., 2001)."

What I can to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to give us more information than this. What citation package are you using? `natbib`? And what `\bibliographystyle`?