# Capital names for author names in citation call-out, normal letters in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing

For my PhD thesis I have to typeset the author's family name in capital letters in the citation call-out but not in the bibliography itself.
So, I mean:

> cite: SCHULTZ, 1971
>
> bibliography: Schultz, T. W. (1971): Book name.

In addition, for several authors I should use hyphen, like this:

> JOSHI - PETERSON, 2013

Could anybody help me how one does this? Thanks.

What I tried so far:
(but I needed capital letters in cite)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}    
\usepackage{amssymb}  

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}    
\bibliographystyle{apalike}  

\begin{document}  

blablabalbal~\citealp{aas2004modelling}  

\bibliography{bibfile}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As Marco Daniel said, many more information are needed. Most importantly, how do you cite: BibTeX (with or without additional citation packages like `natbib`) or BibLaTeX? In case of BibTeX, which `bibliographystyle` and can you use another one? In case of BibLaTeX, did you already redefine anything? Please post a full minimal working example containing all those crucial information.

Comment: Marco Daniel and Manuel Weinkauf many thanks, I edited my question.

Comment: Well, you use `apalike` as your cite style. This is relevant for the formatting. You could try to find a more suitable style, or try to create one with makebst. But since you are apparently writing a report and are not bound to any particular templates, I would suggest to switch to BibLaTeX. All formatting is much more flexible and on-the-fly in this system. A solution for your particular problem could for instance be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30908/biblatex-different-formatting-for-citations-v-bibliography).

Comment: This has alredy been asked here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272458/uppercase-the-author-names-shown-in-citation-call-outs-generated-by-citep

Comment: @Ruben But it never got any answer there, so this reference is not very helpful!

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf -- well, I made this reference for those who want to answer. It is way more sensible to answer questions that are alredy there, right? (and then mark the actual duplicates as such)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stick with BibTeX, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution, make a copy of this file, and name the copy (say) `apalikeCAPS.tex`. (Don't edit an original file of the TEX distribution directly.)
- Open the tile `apalikeCAPS.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In this file, locate the function called `emphasize`. (The function starts on line 200 in my copy of the bst file.)
- After this function, insert the following code:

  ```
  FUNCTION {makeuppercase}
  { duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ "" }
      { "\MakeUppercase{" swap$ * "}" * }
    if$
  }
  ```

  As you can probably guess, this function uppercases its argument.
- Find the function `format.lab.names`. (It should start around line 848, allowing for the 5 or 6 new lines you created when you inserted the new function.) In this function, change the line

  ```
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  ```

  to

  ```
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ makeuppercase
  ```

  In addition, change the line

  ```
           { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
  ```

  to

  ```
           { "--" * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * makeuppercase }
  ```

  Note that the second line has undergone two changes: `" and "` has been replaced with `"--"` (an "en-dash"), and `makeuppercase` has been inserted after `format.name$ *`.
- Save the file `apalikeCAPS.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to also update the filaname database of your TeX distribution.

  - In your main tex file, change the directive `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{apalikeCAPS}` and do a full recompile (latex-bibtex-latex-latex) to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

Aside: As @MarcoDaniel has pointed out in a comment, quite a few of `natbib`s capabilities aren't available if `apalike` (or `apalikeCAPS`) is used as the bibliography style. For instance, the package's `longnamesfirst` option doesn't work, and neither do the "starred" variants (`\citet*`, `\citep*`, etc) of the citation-generating macros. (More precisely, `\citet*` produces the same output as `\citet` does, etc.)

---

The output of a full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{uno,
  author = "Anna Author",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
@misc{due,
  author = "Anne Author and Bertha Buthor",
  title  = "Further Thoughts",
  year   = 3002,
}
@misc{tre,
  author = "Anne Author and Bertha Buthor and Carla Cuthor",
  title  = "Final Thoughts",
  year   = 3003,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalikeCAPS}

\begin{document}
\citep{uno}, \citep{due}, \citep{tre}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should mention that the style apalike can't use the advantages of `natbib`  -- It's the next limitation.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - Are you referring to the fact that `apalike` can *only* generate authoryear-type citation call-outs, and thus that loading `natbib` with the option `numbers` (or `superscripts`...) will generate a crash? For sure, natbib's `\citet`, `\citep`, `\citealt`, `\citealp`, `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` macros all work fine with the `apalike` bibliography style.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - Welcome back, by the way!

Comment: Hi Mico. The documentation of `natbib` says: *[...]Again, only the parenthetical citation is provided.[...]* -- However the test result   contradicts the documentation. (BTW: The star commands are not supported ;-) )

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - Thanks. I'd completely forgotten about natbib's `longnamesfirst` package option and the starred variants of the citation commands. (I never use them in my own papers...) I've added a paragraph to mention some of the issues.

Comment: One more question: how I can reach this "hyphen" stile (instead of and) in the bibliography and that I have colon instead of point after the year: Author, A. - Author, B. (2017): Book name

Comment: @Panni - Didn't you state earlier that you wanted "hyphen style" only in the citation call-outs but not in the formatted bib entries?

Comment: @Mico, you are right, maybe I was not clear enough. I need hypen in both cases. The difference is that in the citation it has to be in capital letters.

Comment: @Panni - In the file `apalikeCAPS.bst`, find the function `format.names`; it should start around line 216. Scroll down about 15 lines to a line that reads `{ " and " * t * }`. In this line, replace `" and "` with `"--"`. Save the file and rerun BibTeX and LaTeX.

Comment: @Mico,  If there are more than 2 authors it makes hyphen just between the last two. Is this correct? How can I reach that in the citetion stays how it is: AUTHOR1-AUTHOR2 et al., but in the bibliography Author1-Author2-Author3-Author4...

Comment: @Panni - I'm really not sure I understand your formatting requirements. For sure, I've *never* written a paper in which the authors' names in the bibliography had to be separated by en-dashes. Please go back to the function `format.names`, find the line that says `{ ", " * t * }`, and in that line replace `", "` with `"--"`.

Comment: @Mico, me neighter...But unfortunatelly this is what I have to do now... And finally it works!!!

Comment: @Panni -- Whew! All's well that ends well... :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you switch to BibLaTeX, you will be able to do both things very easily:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

%Authors in upper case in citations, normal font in bibliography
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\ifcitation{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\ifcitation{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}

%Hyphen between author names
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\space--\space}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\space--\space}

\begin{document}  

blablabalbal \textcite{aas2004modelling}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Author name formatting streamlined. Thanks to Marco Daniel for pointing out the existence of the `ifcitation` command.

Comment: You can use the test `\ifcitation` -- `\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\ifcitation{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\ifcitation{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}`

Comment: Even though the version with `\ifcitation` may be more compact (in a way) it is not at all unusual to use `\AtBeginBibliography` to reset commands for the bibliography.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with macros, without changing `apalike.bst`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2001,
}
@article{two,
  author={W. Riter and P. Enman},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2002,
}
@article{three,
  author={A. Uthor and W. Riter and P. Enman},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2003,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \panniuppercase #1
  {
   \tl_set:Nx #1 { \tl_upper_case:V #1 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_upper_case:n { V }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pannihyphen #1 #2
 {
  \tl_gset:Nn #1 #2
  \tl_greplace_once:Nnn #1 { ~ AND ~ } { - }
  \tl_gset:Nx #1 { { \exp_not:V #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\NAT@split}
  {\gdef\NAT@name}
  {\pannihyphen\NAT@name}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\NAT@parse}
  {\aftergroup}
  {\panniuppercase\NAT@temp\aftergroup}
  {}{\ddt}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\citet{one} \citet{two} \citet{three}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just for making the example self-contained. Use your own bib file.

[image]

Comment: Great solution. I have a short question. You are replacing a global definition by `\gdef` with `\tl_set:Nx`. I had thought that `\tl_gset`is the correct choice.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel You're right. Probably the `\gdef` is not really needed, but…