# Two apalike.bst file in unix texlive distribution: One in ./local/texlive/2016.. and other in ./share/texlive/

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

In trying to force the author name to be in capital letters in citation while keeping normal letters in the reference list. In this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354981/capital-names-for-author-names-in-citation-call-out-normal-letters-in-bibliogra) there is an answer that suggests small changes in the file **apalike.bst** as a way to achieve this goal. Well, for my surprise, when I searching for the mentioned file through the folders of my linux distribuition, I got two matches instead of one. The two files apalike.bst are in the following paths:

> ./local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/apalike.bst
>
> ./share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/apalike.bst

From the exposed, my questions is:

1. What is the purpose to be two copies of this file?
2. Which one should I copy and change to achive what I want?
3. There is a better solution to work around this issue with natbib?

Comment: Did you install vanilla TeX Live and the repository version?

Comment: you presumably have two of everything eg `article.cls` not just that bst file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I have also two version of article.cls. So basically I have two version of texlive installed? If this is the casa, how can I know which one I am using and which I am not and probably can be deleted?

Comment: That's easy to check: Use your distribution's package manager to look up the package `texlive` (on Debian-based Distros you may search for `texlive-bin`). If it's installed then you have the repository version on your system. After that check if you have also all programs (e.g. `pdflatex`) in `/usr/local/texlive/2016`. If yes, you also have the "vanilla" version.

Comment: just look in any log file where the full paths are shown they are either under /usr/local or  /share depending on which  tex executable is first in your path

Comment: @DavidCarlisle suggests I check a log file. From this I got that I am using the files from the folder ../local/. So I using the vanilla version, which means one installed without the package manager. Is it right?

Comment: yes you are using last years vanilla texlive (texlive 2017 is current) note it's best not to simply delete the debian package managed version as you will confuse the package manager, although if disk space is a concern there some answers on this site how to install "stub" debian packages so that it knows that tex is installed.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu